# Niveles de seguridad utilizando Python y Selenium para navegar en Internet

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Existen paginas que detectan la presencia de Selenium aun siguiendo los siguientes puntos.

- Desactivando Java
- Cambiando IP con TOR
- Cambiando User Agent
- Borrando Cookies
- Borrando Cache

DESABILITANDO JAVA

```
firefox_profile.set_preference( "javascript.enabled", False )
```

CAMBIANDO IP

```
with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

CAMBIANDO USER AGENT

```
ua = UserAgent()
random_ua = ua.random
```

BORRANDO COOKIES

```
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

BORRANDO CACHE

```
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
```

Alguna otra idea para evitar que las paginas detecten selenium como bot automatico?